# Equalizer diagram equipped with other arrows

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I am trying to draw this diagram and can't get slopped arrows right.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need anything special for that, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.4cm,column sep=1.6cm]
& FU_i \arrow[r,"F(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_i)"] & F(U_i\cap U_j)\\
FU \arrow[r,dashed,"e"] \arrow[dr] \arrow[ur]
& \prod\limits_i FU_i \arrow[d] \arrow[u]
\arrow[r,dashed,"q"',yshift=-2pt] \arrow[r,dashed,"p",yshift=2pt]&
\prod\limits_{i,j}F(U_i\cap U_j)
\arrow[d] \arrow[u]\\
& FU_j \arrow[r,"F(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_j)"']& F(U_i\cap U_j)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]