# Diagram with arrows connecting equalizers

Tags: arrows

Can someone help me with this please?
[image]

Comment: You already asked a very similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431808/121799). So the least thing you could/should do is to use its answer, try to modify it, and if you got stuck ask a question with the code you have. (BTW, the downvote is not from me.)

Comment: you are right @marmot . i forgot about that, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.4cm,column sep=1.6cm]
FU \arrow[r]\arrow[d] & \prod\limits_kF_k\bigl(U\cap \omega_k\bigr) 
 \arrow[r,yshift=2pt] \arrow[r,yshift=-2pt]\arrow[d]&
 \prod\limits_{k,\ell}F_k\bigl(U\cap \omega_k\cap\omega_\ell\bigr) \arrow[d]
\\
\prod\limits_iFU_i \arrow[r]\arrow[d] & 
\prod\limits_i\prod\limits_kF_k\bigl(U_i\cap \omega_k\bigr) 
 \arrow[r,yshift=2pt] \arrow[r,yshift=-2pt]\arrow[d]&
 \prod\limits_i\prod\limits_{k,\ell}F_k\bigl(U_i\cap \omega_k\cap\omega_\ell\bigr) 
 \arrow[d]
\\
\prod\limits_{i,j}F(U_i\cap U_j) \arrow[r] & 
\prod\limits_{i,j}\prod\limits_kF_k\bigl((U_i\cap U_j)\cap \omega_k\bigr) 
 \arrow[r,yshift=2pt]
 \arrow[r,yshift=-2pt]&
 \prod\limits_{i,j}\prod\limits_{k,\ell}F_k\bigl((U_i\cap U_j)\cap \omega_k\cap\omega_\ell
 \bigr) 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: instead `\arrow[r,yshift=2pt] \arrow[r,yshift=-2pt]` you can also write `\arrow[r,shift left] \arrow[r,shift right]`.